# Swift Initializer of a Class

Tags: swift, class

I've started to learn swift a couple days ago and i come from a java/c++ background.
However this piece of a code has a mistake that i cant seem to be able to fix.

```
class Student
{
    var number:Int
    var name:String
    var course:String

    init(_ name:String,_ number:Int, _ course:String)
    {
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
        self.course = course
    }

    func write()
    {
        print("Name:",self.name)
        print("Number:",self.number)
        print("Course:",self.course)
    }
}

class ExchangeStudent:Student
{
    var country:String

   init(_ name:String,_ number:Int, _ course:String, _country:String)
    {
        super.init(name,number,course)
        self.country = country
    }

}
```

However i get the following error:

```
property 'self.country' not initialized at super.init call
```

And i don't really understand how i can solve it

Comment: please, use proper Swift code style, this code hurts my eyes :(

Answer (score 1):

The call to `super.init` needs to come **after** you have initialised all extra properties added by the subclass.

```
class ExchangeStudent: Student {
    var country:String

    init(_ name:String,_ number:Int, _ course:String, _ country:String) {
        self.country = country
        super.init(name,number,course)
    }

}
```

Comment: ahhhh, that was what i was missing. Thanks a lot!